# uncomment XML content with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a problem with XML and XSLT.
I have one XML file with some comment and I want to uncomment it.

For example:

```
<my-app>
 <name>
 </name>
  <!-- <class>
         <line></line>
   </class>-->
</my-app>
```

I want to uncomment this commented tag.

Comment: please edit your code, it's hidden

Comment: Hi, is there a reason why it is commented out in the first place?

Comment: for some reason we have commented but while doing some other operation i need this to be uncommented

Comment: ok, so it is commented out so that other places that the file is used can ignore it.

Could you uncomment and rename the node, so the other operations that use the file will not find the "class" node and keep behaving as expected?

Comment: thanks for your reply,
We have some restriction, we cant do it manually thats why i have to do with xslt. Actually this file is inside war file while extracting the war we need to modify the web.xml file through xslt.

Comment: i got the solution 
thanks allot for your help
here is solution
<=================>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()"> 
     <xsl:copy> 
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> 
     </xsl:copy> 
   </xsl:template> 
   <xsl:template match="comment()[contains(., '&lt;class&gt;')]"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/> 
   </xsl:template>
     
</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<!-- the identity template copies everything 
     (unless more specific templates apply) -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- this template matches comments and uncomments them -->
<xsl:template match="comment()">
  <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

Be aware that `disable-output-escaping="yes"` implies that the comment contents should be well-formed.

Comment: thanks allot for your,but i i could see one more problem like it will uncomment all the comment which i dont want so please help me here is the xml 
<my-app>
<!--using same -->
 <name>
 </name>
  <!-- <class>
         <line></line>
   </class>-->
</my-app>

and expected result look like 

<my-app>
<!--using same -->
 <name>
 </name>
   <class>
      <line></line>
   </class>
</my-app>

thanks in advance

Comment: Change `match="comment()"` to something like `match="comment()[contains(., '</')]"`. This makes it apply to comments only that look a bit like HTML. Not perfect, but maybe sufficient for this application.

Answer (score 2):

If one use Saxon, saxon:parse() is cleaner, because it creates a real XML structure.
saxon:parse($xml as xs:string) ==> document-node()
In xsl:stylesheet element, add xmlns:saxon=http://saxon.sf.net/

Example:

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:variable name="comment" select="saxon:parse(.)" as="document-node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$comment"/>
</xsl:template>
```